# Flagging a Question as Not belonging that I've answered

Tags: bug, status-norepro

---

**EDIT**

This only occurs on [one given question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/3559/2626).  I've had no luck recreating this on other questions regardless of any other variables. So strange.

---

When I attempt to flag a question as "it doesn't belong here", it used to provide a list of options with radial boxes next to them.

Well... the radial boxes are gone.  Therefore, (since I can't select an option) you can't flag questions as off topic.

I've tried this on IE8, Firefox 5, Firefox 6, Chrome 13, and Opera 11. (Also in an [archived version of IE7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vISk.jpg)--not the standard IE7 installation, though.)

This isn't a permissions issue is it?

[image]

Comment: seems to work in Chrome, and working fine in Firefox 5.0.1 for me.

Comment: screenshot it for me Richard, please. I have a feeling I know this problem. Also, try a hard refresh. I had this once before.

Comment: Ok, the way it looks in the image, it should be fine the way it is, so it's some sort of render problem _most likely_. However, I'm gonna punt this one upstream for now, until I can check some other things on this end (oh why don't I have a sockpuppet account yet)

Comment: sounds like maybe javascript caching problems? we can't reproduce.

Comment: @Jeff can we repro with flag then VtC?

Comment: I'm unable to select an item (even by clicking on the label).  However, since this is only occurring on that one question (even still), I don't mind this issue being closed.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** Can't reproduce after answering this question... but, I answered in Safari and am trying to reproduce in other browsers, so that may not be a good test. Also, this is Meta, not the main site, so that may make a difference.

But, as Cole said, it should be fine as your screenshot shows. You can click anywhere in the reasons (either the bold labels or the descriptions) to select a reason. So the radio buttons are missing but the UI should still be *functional* -- is it?

---

Works for me, IE 8.0.7600:

[image: IE8 Screencap]

Firefox 5.0.1:

[image: Firefox Screencap]

And in IE 7:
[image: IE7 Screencap]

Comment: Thanks Josh. Appreciate the doublecheck with a low value account.

Comment: Hey! Who you calling low value @jcolebrand?!?! ;-)

Comment: I particularly like the expert use of ... paint?

Comment: @DTest: Freehand Circles FTW! (I'm an MSO addict, what can I say? :-)